# Random Number Guessing Game C#

Tags: c#

I have having two issues with my code currently that I can't seem to figure out how to fix, they worked before, but now they don't work at all.

What I'm having trouble with is when the user get's the right answer it's not showing the dialogue to ask if they wish to end or play again. And if I get to that dialogue when the user doesn't guess the right number in the amount of guesses, and the user selects y (yes) to continue, it doesn't and just hangs.

Here is what I have currently, since if I can get this figured out, then the others should be easier.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RandomNumberGame
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random gen = new Random();
            int number;
            bool over = false;
            string userChoice;
            int guess = 0;
            int counter = 0;

            while (!over)
            {
                over = true;
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Easy: 1 - 10");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Medium: 1 - 50");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Hard: 1 - 100");
                Console.Write("Please input the number of the difficulty you wish to  play: ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (str)
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.WriteLine("You chose easy difficulty.");
                    number = gen.Next(1, 11);

                    Console.WriteLine("I'm thinking of a number between 1 - 10");
                        for (guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); guess != number; guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()))
                        {
                            if (guess < 1 || guess > 10)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 - 10");
                            }
                            else if (guess < number)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Higher");
                                counter++;
                                Console.WriteLine("You have " + (5 - counter) + " attempts left");
                            }
                            else if (guess > number)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Lower");
                                counter++;
                                Console.WriteLine("You have " + (5 - counter) + " attempts left");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    Console.WriteLine("You have guessed correctly! It only took you: " + number + " tries.");
                                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");
                                    userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
                                    if (userChoice == "n")
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!");
                                        Environment.Exit(0);
                                    }
                                    else if (userChoice == "y")
                                    {
                                        over = false;
                                    }
                            }
                            if (counter == 5)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, you didn't guess it under 5 attempts.");
                                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");
                                userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
                                if (userChoice == "n")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!");
                                    Environment.Exit(0);
                                }
                                else if (userChoice == "y")
                                {
                                    over = false;
                                }
                           }
                        }
                    break;
```

Comment: You should set `counter` to zero when you select the replay option, I believe. Also, don't use `Environment.Exit`, there's usually a better way - in this case, a simple `return` will work as a much cleaner option :)

Comment: that looks like quite bad abuse of a for loop to me for a start, it should be a `do/while(guess != number)` imo. then once your out of this loop (i.e correct guess) you ask the user for input

Comment: As a pure side comment: Your code would be MUCH easier if  you use methods / functions.
You could drastically shorten the switch (str) element.
Also: you are not validating user input, which is a reipce for disaster (e.g. enter A)

Comment: when the user enters the correct number `guess != number` will evaluate to false and your else statement in your for loop won't be executed.

Comment: Well, the OP is obviously a beginner. We could discuss the code review for quite a while, but that probably isn't all that helpful at this point - and should be left for e.g. Code Review SE. And @itsaferbie, you might find it quite helpful to try and debug the program. Set breakpoints where the failure condition starts, and then step until you find the issue.

Comment: @Luaan - In this instance, I believe the flow of the code *is* the problem, there are a lot of other things that could be mentioned but my original comment only addresses the specific issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a little bit of restructuring as per my comment should help you a lot here

```
Console.WriteLine("I'm thinking of a number between 1 - 10");
do
{
    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out guess))
    {
        //not valid number - enter again
    }
    //insert your if statement about whether guess is correct
    if(counter >= 5)
    {
        //unable to guess in 5 moves
        break;
    }
}while(guess != number)
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (y/n)");
userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
if (userChoice == "n")
{
    over = true;
}
```

---

```
List<int> guesses = new List<int>()

bool guessed = true;
while(guessed)
{
    foreach(int g in guesses)
    {
         if(g == guess)
         {
             break;
         }
    }
    guesses.Add(guess);
    guessed = false;

}
```

Comment: I used this example to help me understand what was going on and it helped tremendously. Thanks for this!

Comment: @itsaferbie - No worries, glad it helped. I didn't mention it in my answer but you should try to let your program flow naturally instead of using  `environment.exit` (hence why I just set the outer while loops variable to true)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that, I was just seeing it being used on other examples, and thought that it was good to use. Now I know better! :D

Comment: @itsaferbie - It can be good to use but I'll let you research when that would be as and when you need it ;)

Comment: Right now I'm trying to store user input to and array to make sure they don't make the same guess twice. Could you help me understand what to do, because so far all that I've looked up has confused me. Thank you.

Comment: @itsaferbie - I've added two small snippets to help (Its incomplete and untested)

Answer (score 1):

When your guess is correct you are not entering into the `for`

```
for (guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); guess != number; guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()))
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Options to improve:**

1.Keep the for, but use it as the counter instead, e.g.

```
for (var counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
{
    var guess = int.Parse(...);
    ... 
}
```

> Smaller scopes of variables ease debugging a lot (e.g. the example
>   with not resetting the counter to zero). –  [Luaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3032289/luaan)

2.Replace `for` with `while`

```
const int maxCount = 5;
int counter = 0;
while ((guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) != number && counter++ < maxCount)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Or, keep the `for`, but use it as the counter instead, e.g. `for (var counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) { var guess = int.Parse(...); ... }`. Smaller scopes of variables ease debugging a lot (e.g. the example with not resetting the `counter` to zero).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if its the main problem, but try adding a `continue` statement after your set `over = false` and use `return` instead of `Environment.Exit(0);`